# How to connect to an alternative local postgresql cluster for the fist time?

Tags: postgresql

In Ubuntu 16.04 I created second postgres database cluster, called **cmg**, with a local user as the admin user:

```
pg_create -u "local_username" -g "local_usergroup" -d /path/to/data/dir 9.5  cmg
```

The cluster was started with:

```
pg_ctrlcluster 9.5 cmg start
```

which ran successfully (`pg_lsclusters` show both are online)

The problem is I cannot connect to the cluster using psql as is normally done.

I tried using:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -w -p5433  -U local_username
```

which fails with:

```
psql: fe_sendauth: no password supplied"
```

Is there any way to connect to the specific cluster?

Comment: try `psql -h your_socket_dir -w -p5433 -U postgres` and check if you have the user `local_username`. btw - did you type in any password?.. in case it did not ask, try adding `-W`

Comment: Thanks @Vao-Tsun your suggestion with slight alteration worked. Ended up with:  'psql -h /tmp/ -p 5433 -d potsgres'. With the currently logged in user being the admin user ('local_user'). Please add it as answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use `psql -h your_socket_dir -p5433 -U postgres` to connect locally (uses peer auth by default - thus high chahce to login wothout password)

once logged in - set up password (create user if needed) and use it connecting remotely

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p5433  -U local_username
```

in your connect string you had `-w` which is never ask for a password https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html which would by default work only for local connections

Answer (score 0):

I think the default `pg_hba.conf` when you start up a new cluster expects you to authenticate with `peer` connections, so you need to change user to your local user before connecting

```
[root@server~]# su - local_username
>> Enter password:
> password
[local_username@server~]# psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5433
```

You can check your `pg_hba.conf` file in `/path/to/data/dir/pg_hba.conf` to see how it expects you to authenticate.

Alternatively, if you cannot get access as your `'local_username'` then instead su to `postgres` user in the instructions above and it should work